# how to set OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter stateless value in application context XML

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

It seems OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter has changed in spring-security-oauth version 2.0.6 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28283029/3448468)). Now I need to set stateless to false. How to do that in the application context XML? (cannot comment on the original post for lack of permission)

Answer (score 0):

You could inject it into one of your own beans and set the flag in a `@PostConstruct` I think. Better to raise an issue in github if you want a new feature in the XML though probably.